# Погрешности GPS и варианты борьбы с ними

Tags: android, gps

Стоит задача подсчета метров по GPS на малой скорости движения (3-5км/ч) и соответственно на малых расстояниях (от 0.5 метра и выше). При реализации задачи получаем огромную погрешность (20-100 метров) между изменениями координат (когда вызывается `onLocationChanged` каждую секунду).

Понятно, что GPS-приемник в смартфоне слабее и сама точность от спутника не супер, но может кто-то знает как можно улучшить точность расчетов, какой-либо алгоритм или вообще какие-либо интересные особенности, сторону в которую стоит копать?

Я пока не уверен, что на малых расстояниях задача впринципе реализуема :( Возможно потому что нужно уйти в дебри навигации.

Comment: Это у вас координаты определяются наверное не по спутникам, а по вышкам связи или wifi устройствам... Вырубите в настройках возможность использования не спутников (не знаю как, но что-то подобное должно быть)

Comment: gps-провайдер в коде:) или я не так понял?

Comment: Не знаю я не сильно разбираюсь в локейшн сервисах, но может имело бы смысл посчитать количество спутников там и проч. детали?

Comment: Да, 32 штуки обычно(Ростов-на-Дону). Точность у гпс просто корявая :) а точнее у гпс-приемников в смартфонах.

Comment: Скажите, удалось ли чего-то добиться в решении задачи? Я пока вижу это так:
1. Создаем массив координат, полученных, допустим за 1 секунду
2. Находим среднее арифметическое
3. Вычисляем для каждой координаты расстояние от средней арифметической
4. Находим СКО.
5. Удаляем по одному из алгоритмов элементы, резко выделяющиеся из результатов.
6. Находим среднее арифметическое и принимаем за действительные координаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное решение, которое пока что удалось найти - так это поиск мат ожидания от всех получаемых координат за каждую секунду. Результат становится чуть более сглаженным. Также, думаю стоит добавить какие-либо условия на допустимые границы: к примеру мы знаем скорость движения или предполагаем, что человек идет и так как координаты мы получаем каждую секунду, то примерные изменения мы можем отфильтровать, задействовав к тому же датчики.

Пока что так.

Answer (score 0):

Когда собирался делать диплом по этой теме, меня предостерегали, что будут погрешности, но 20-100 метров - это как-то слишком, мне говорили о 3-10. Бороться с ними предлагали с помощью акселерометра / гироскопа.

Comment: Максимум - это определить двигаемся или нет. Ну это понятно, только на точность координат при движении не влияет. Так что, не верное было предложение.