# Точность GPS данных

Tags: gps

У меня есть модуль GNSS Quectel L76, я получаю с него координаты и хочу знать точность этих координат, то есть погрешность в метрах. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идёт о непосредственной обработке протокола NMEA, в нём передаются параметры ухудшения точности:
`PDOP (Position Dilution of Precision)` - снижение точности по местоположению - передаётся в сообщениях $GPGSA,$PGRMF
`HDOP (Horizontal Dilution of Precision)` - снижение точности в горизонтальной плоскости - передаётся в сообщениях $GPGSA, $GPGGA
`VDOP (Vertical Dilution of Precision)` - снижение точности в вертикальной плоскости - передаётся в сообщени $GPGSA
`TDOP (Time dilution of precision)` - снижение точности по времени - передаётся в сообщени $PGRMF

Преобразовать погрешности в метры, затруднительно, т.к. это оценочные величины. Для уточнения этой возможности, следует читать документацию на приёмник.

UPD: Обычно, для упрощения, умножают HDOP на погрешность приёмника.

Answer (score 1):

Типичная точность определения координат GPS приемниками в горизонтальной плоскости составляет примерно 1-2 метра (при условии хорошей видимости небосвода). Точность определения высоты над уровнем моря обычно в 2-5 раз ниже, чем точность определения координат в тех же условиях (т.е. в идеальных условиях 2-10 метра).

Уровень приёма сигнала от спутников, а как следствие и точность определения координат, ухудшается под плотной листвой деревьев или из-за очень большой облачности. Также нормальному приёму сигналов GPS могут повредить помехи от многих наземных радиоисточников. Однако, главным фактором, влияющим на снижение точности GPS, является неполная видимость небосвода. Особенно ярко это проявляется при нахождении GPS приемника в условиях плотной городской застройки, когда значительная часть небосвода скрыта рядом расположенными строениями, навесами и прочими препятствиями. Точность определения координат при этом может падать до 20-30 метров, а иногда и более. Препятствия не пропускают сигналы от части потенциально доступных в данной точке Земли спутников. Это приводит к тому, что расчеты ведутся по меньшему числу сигналов от спутников, находящихся преимущественно в одном секторе небосвода. Смещение при этом возникает обычно в перпендикулярной плоскости относительно препятствия.

Вообще, если говорить о точности GPS в условиях города, на основе накопленных статистических данных и собственного опыта можно сделать следующие выводы. Точность определения координат при нахождении транспортного средства на открытой местности (парковки, площади и пр.) и при движении по крупным автомагистралям, многополосным дорогам будет составлять 1-2 метра. При движении по узким улицам, особенно, когда вдоль них имеются близко расположенные дома, точность составит 4-10 метров. При нахождении автомобиля в "дворовых колодцах", очень близко к высотным домам и т.п. точность может падать вплоть до 20-30 метров.

Comment: Дело в том, что я видел такую информацию в некоторых android приложениях, например GpsStatus, и мне не понятно, как его считают. Мой модуль работает с GPS и ГЛОНАСС одновременно.

Comment: @Владислав там наверняка реализована корректировка с использованием данных от вышек связи или wifi устройств. Возможно вам  пригодится информация из этого вопроса: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/143695/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-gps-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Для ответа на подобные вопросы, неплохо смотреть даташиты. Вот к примеру, легко находиться, что точность [меньше 2.5 метра](http://satron.ru/product/Quectel/L76#features).

Comment: Да, я его даташит очень хорошо знаю. Но цифра эта мне не совсем понятна. И я видел на некоторых форумах, как эту цифру умножают на HDOP.  Но нету нигде пояснений по этому поводу.

Comment: Это число говорит о том, что когда модуль gps выйдет в рабочий режим, то реальное положение будет отличаться от измеренного не более чем на 2.5 метра.